# How to do Data driven testing in Selenium without excel file or Database

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, data-driven-tests

I have recently been into an interview where I was asked that how will I do the data-driven testing in selenium without using an excel sheet or database.......
The interviewer said that you can not use Apache POI and JDBC connection......
I told him that then we can make a configure.properties file and  use the values from there by reading that file in the constructor of the base class and then use it across our project... ( I know that it was not at all a convincing answer and  interviewer was not looking convinced too)

I tried to search StackOverflow for this but there was nothing that I could find relating to this..,
I have 3 years of exp. in selenium automation using Java as a binding language and was surprised with the question.....
Is there really any way of doing data-driven testing without excel and database......means we are supposed to get our data from somewhere.....plz help me on this...
Thanks.....

Comment: You can get data from the API or use XMLs, CSVs, JSON... Any data structure you want. Even TXT.

Comment: Thanks, Fenio.....i was not aware of this JSON concept for data-driven testing...I will look into this now...

Answer (score 0):

```
Yes you can , just give data set into your tests by Dataprovider annotation
 // create 2 d array if you you have 2 data fields like uname and password

    @Dataprovider(name="Testdata")
 Public Object[][]  getData()
{
  // creating 2 data sets
Object[][] data=new Object[2][2];
data[0][0]="username1"
data[0][1]="username2"
data[1][0]="password1"
data[1][1]="password2"`enter code here`
return data;
 }
```

Comment: You need to use TestNG in your project.

Comment: Or you can use `@Parameters` from JUnit